# How can I check in PHP if 2 IPv6-Adresses are equal?

Tags: php, ipv6

I want to check if an IP is whitelisted, but IPv6-Adresses can have different representations:

For example `2001:0DB8:0:0:1::1` is the short form of `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0001:0000:0000:0001`.

Thus, string comparison doesn't work. How can I know two adresses are equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [inet_pton](https://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php).

```
function is_ip_equal($ip1, $ip2) {
    return inet_pton($ip1) == inet_pton($ip2);
}
```

(However, this will only work if PHP was not compiled with `--disable-ipv6 option`. You can check this by using `if (!defined('AF_INET6')) echo "IPv6 support was disabled";`).

Answer (score 0):

`inet_pton` does not strip out the brackets in bracketed IPv6 addresses, which matters only to very specific use-cases: `inet_pton("[::1]")` returns FALSE. This is because bracketed addresses are technically not valid IPv6 addresses (instead, the bracketed address *contains* an IPv6 address) even though the brackets are required when the IPv6 is in a URL.

Here is the Ipv6-only function:

```
$bothBracketsArray = array('[', ']');
function are_ipv6_equal($a, $b) {
    global $bothBracketsArray;
    return inet_pton(str_replace($bothBracketsArray, '', $a)) === inet_pton(str_replace($bothBracketsArray, '', $b));
}
```

The `$bothBracketsArray` is made a global so PHP doesn't have to allocate a new array each time or make a shallow clone of its template (or whatever it is that PHP is doing nowadays).

My own purposes also required comparing port numbers and dealing with IPv4 because I am monitoring the output from netstat to see which process PID is on the other side of the socket.

```
$bothBracketsArray = array('[', ']');
function doIpsAndPortsEqual($a, $b) {
    global $bothBracketsArray;
    $lastPosA = strrpos($a, ":"); // port #
    $lastPosB = strrpos($b, ":"); // port #
    if (substr($a, $lastPosA+1) !== substr($b, $lastPosB+1)) return false;
    $ipA = substr($a, 0, $lastPosA);
    $ipB = substr($a, 0, $lastPosB);
    if (strpos($ipA, ':') !== false) { // Ipv6
        return inet_pton(str_replace($bothBracketsArray, '', $ipA)) === inet_pton(str_replace($bothBracketsArray, '', $ipB));
    } else { // Ipv4
        return $ipA === $ipB;
    }
}
```